MariaDB dropped function but getting error creating
I have dropped a function on MariaDb then creating again mariadb warn allready exists that function then ispect from dbeaver and there is nothing. I have dropped again that function and warn function does not exists . simpyle ı can not delete or create that function. I have restarted mariadb and error is still continiue

I have restarted Database and dump&create function and also search with database management app there is noting. And also ı tried with delimiter creating function

I would open the file dump_procedures.sql in a text editor and search it for the function definition. Does it define the same function twice?

Unless your copy and paste keys are broken: Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

I have checked and the function exists only once

Try adding IF NOT EXISTS to the function create to see if that helps. CREATE FUNCTION IF NOT EXISTS ...

There is not too much insight in your code to give more specific answers.
Please check:

If the dump file does not contain the definition of the funtion twice (once in row 374 and once before that one)
If the dump file specifies a database. It could be, that you believe that you are applying the dump to database A (where you have previously dropped the function) but the dump tries to define the function in database B, where it is already present.
If you have committed your changes after the drop

